# Quantify file changes

Tags: python, c++, c, unix, operating-system

I'm looking for a way to quantify the changes made to a file. That is, if I have a file with something written on, and I edit it and save it, is there a way to know (using Python or C/C++) how much the files has changed?

For example, if my file is "aaaaaaaaaaa" and I change it to "aaabbbbbbb", that quantification method should yield a greater result (assuming thats quantifiable) than if I had changed it to "aaaaaaaaaba".

Hope I made myself clear,

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
It is supposed to be done without actually reading the file.

Comment: probably not without some kind of version control. I know in Git, you do something like "git diff HEAD my_file" which will mark changed lines.

Comment: Are you looking for the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)?

Comment: I didn't make myself clear, I edited the question

Comment: "Without reading the file" ... how is that supposed to happen, then?

Comment: You want to quantify the modification of a file you don't read ? Here you just can compare the weight of the last file and the new file. If you don't read it, it will be hard to compare something else.

Comment: Well, that's what I wanted to know if is possible ;). There could be some hash-like property of the file that would change on save proportionally to the changes made to the file.

Answer (score 1):

On a lines you could use diff.

To Edit: xor_hash(new) - xor_hash(old)

Comment: no it is a algorithm you have to create yourself. what I left out is that you need a key you'll be using for both files. And both files must have the same length

Comment: But, from what I understand, it involves reading the file's lines, etc.

Comment: but how else do you want to compare the content of a file?

Comment: Ok, I'll go straight to the point: If a commercial program uses that method on your files, is that considered spyware?

Comment: I'm not a Lawyer, I don't know. But can you compare something to something else without looking at both.

Comment: Or do you mean I can compare previous and current file without looking at it?

Comment: No. Comparing means looking

Comment: you can stat the old and new file to determine if a change has been made, but not how much of a change.

Comment: you can bump the modification time without modifying the file.